# Coefficient of $x^k$ in ${(1 - e^x)}^{-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, binomial-theorem

> What is the coefficient of $x^k$ in ${(1 - e^x)}^{-n}$?

This is what I tried-

Using negative binomial expansion and Taylor series expansion of $e^t$, 
$${(1 - e^x)}^{-n} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {n+i-1 \choose i} e^{ix} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {n+i-1 \choose i} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^t x^t}{t!} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^t}{t!} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^t {n+i-1 \choose i} $$
But I couldn't proceed further. Does a closed form for the coefficient of $x^k$ exists?

Also, I would like to calculate the value of the first $k$ coefficients of the above expansion. Is there an efficient algorithm for it?

Comment: That's not going to converge...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you tell why I am not able to get it?

Comment: You are expanding in growing powers. You want to expand in decaying powers. So factor the $e^x$ out of the parentheses and then expand after that.

Comment: For $n=1$, you'll get Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} B_j \frac{x^j}{j!}$$
where $$B_j=\sum_{m=0}^j\frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^i\binom mi i^j$$
is the $j$-th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).
Hence
$$[x^k]{(1 - e^x)}^{-n}=(-1)^n[x^{k+n}]\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^n
=(-1)^n\sum_{j_1+\dots+j_n=n+k}\frac{B_{j_1}}{j_1!}\cdots \frac{B_{j_n}}{j_n!}$$
where $j_1,\dots,j_n$ are non-negative integers.

P.S. For example for $n=3$ and for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$, the coefficients are:
$$\frac{3}{8},-\frac{19}{240},\frac{1}{160},\frac{1}{945},-\frac{1}{4032},-\frac{19}{1209600}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Robert. Can you also give an algorithm for the second part of the question.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Explicit_definition

Comment: I know of an algorithm to compute Bernoulli numbers using dynamic programming. But how to calculate the coefficient of $x^k$, say for all $k <= 10$, I understand your formula but am not able to translate it into an efficient algorithm which I can code.

Comment: What about $n$? Have you range for it? I am afraid that there is no easy formula here. In the nested loops, by symmetry, it suffices to consider that $0\leq j_1\leq \dots\leq  j_n$ such that $j_1+\dots+j_n=n+k$. As regards $B_j$, I gave you an explicit formula.

Comment: Thanks for an example @Robert. There are bounds on the product of $n$ and $k$. The product is less than ${10}^5$. Can you suggest an algorithm for this?

Comment: @joinit I am sorry, but I have no further suggestions at the moment.